# Disable PAGESPEED SCRIPT INJECTION to IMAGE in theme files

Tags: javascript, cache, bug

Since a few days I am bugged with INJECTION of PAGESPEED scripts for every image  all across my theme files, and it just messes up the code (though it doesn't break the site). I want this to be removed somehow!!! I tried manual deletion but (it reappears on next load), and then I found it could be a prob of cloudflare that I use and disable all settings on cloudflare but still didn't work! 
Is there some way I can disable it? Somehow.

[image: Here is one instance where the code is messed up]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be caused by the [mod_pagespeed](https://www.modpagespeed.com/) Apache module. You should talk to your hoster to disable this.

Comment: This is definitely caused by mod_pagespeed. Author should ask holster to turn it off, or  try to use my plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/kagg-pagespeed-module/ which allows to turn off pagespeed module. This cause, however, `?ModPagespeed=off` to be added to every site url.

Comment: I use custom Amazon AWS, and I don't think Amazon is doing this since it wasn't there for the last few years. I think its Cloudflare which is responsible for it, but I tried disabling all Cloudflare features, but it had no impact.

Comment: I am not able to understand how it is able to put the script inside my theme files (i.e. on every img tag in my theme), and it even puts a </head> tag on template files. Maybe I can use the plugin, but I am curious how it actually crept in????

Comment: @KAGGDesign I tried your plugin, but it doesn't work to help me out.